# Which program modified /etc/resolv.conf?

Tags: networking, debian-squeeze

I'm using Network Manager to auto connect to wireless network. I have setup my personal DNS server using BIND 9.

[image: screenshot]

After connected, it seems just fine:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

But 30 minutes or so later, the file /etc/resolv.conf is overwritten by unknown program and its contents became:

```
domain domain
search domain
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

The question is, how can I know what program changed /etc/resolv.conf? Or, how can I force it to use local nameserver?

Comment: Looks like a DHCP client is messing with your resolv.conf. Try using *auditd* daemon if you have 2.6+ kernel.

Comment: My kernel is 2.6.32-5-686, though, it warns me `auditd start runlevel arguments (S) do not match LSB Default-Start values (2 3 4 5)`.

Comment: [Man auditd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd) ;)

Comment: Having checked the audit.log, it seems `/etc/resolv.conf` is overwritten with `/etc/resolv.conf.dhclient-new` by `/bin/mv`. But I had not even installed dhcp-client yet, what can I do now?

Comment: Is this an authoritative name server? If so, you should not be using dynamic IP addresses anway. Use a static configuration.

Comment: `rpm -qa dhclient` will show you if its installed

Comment: @Sirex: I'm using apt package manager, and I had found it's in the `isc-dhcp-client` package, which is dependent of `network-manager`. So, it seems network-manager doesn't configured DHCP client well as expected.

Comment: @Keith: What's authoritative name server? My DNS server provides: internet zones (`zone "." { type hint; ...}`, and some private zones. The purpose of a private DNS server is to prevent from external DNS attack/rewrite (specially, the gov), and also for local networking.

Comment: i tend to end up setting /etc/resolv.conf as chattr +i to be honest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's almost certainly a DHCP client (dhclient, apparently, based on your comment) resetting `resolv.conf` to match the values it's receiving from the DHCP server.

To, erm, resolve this issue, locate `dhclient.conf` (I have it at `/etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf` in Ubuntu) and use the `prepend domain-name-servers` command to place your own DNS before the DHCP server's values or `supersede domain-name-servers` to only use your own, completely ignoring those given by DHCP.

Comment: `supersede domain-name-servers` does work, though, I'm curious why network-manager could mess up with DHCP client, there is only one DHCP client, isn't it?